# How to set a Component's property value from inside a FileReader event

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have this component:

```
export class FileFormComponent {
  _base64: string;

 handleFile($event){
   var input = $event.target;
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onloadend = function() {
     this._base64 = reader.result
   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   console.log(this._base64);
 }
}
```

The problem is the `console.log(this._base64)` logs `undefined`. It seems `this` inside the `onloadend` event does not refer to the component's context. how can I set the value of the `_base64` property from inside the `FileReader` `onloadend` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an arrow function. This way you could use the lexical this (that corresponds to the component instance):

```
reader.onloadend() = () => {
  this._base64 = reader.result
}
```

See this link for more details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: It's just because your `console.log` is called before the `onloadend` callback  ;-)

Comment: You could bind your `_base64` property in the view to see its value. Something like that: `{{_base64}}`. This way you will see if the value is updated...

Comment: still getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I use for situations like this one, is:

```
var self = this;
reader.onloadend = function(){
    console.log(self._base64);
}
```

Comment: This is a solution in JavaScript, but in TypeScript the arrow-function is the way to go. It does not change the `this` reference.

Comment: Thank you for educating me :)